# List View web part missing for one user

Tags: 2013, web-part, personalization

After spending some time searching for this with no luck, I decided to post incase other are looking...

SharePoint 2013. Custom List, nothing special... One user navigates to a page with a list view web part for the custom list. The title for the list shows up, but non of the other content. She cannot see the "new item or edit this list" options, any of the columns, nor any of the items.

I have confirmed that she can navigate to the list and view through site content, so permission is not the issue. I have removed the web part and added again. Same result.

Answer (score 3):

2013 allows people with contribute access to 'Personalize this Page'. This user clicked their name, clicked 'Personalize this Page', then minimized the web part.

To revert the change, had the user click their name, then 'Reset Page Content'.
Note that this option only appears after the page has been 'personalized'.

Hope no one else spends as much time on this as I did.